# How do I create a quiz app for pictures to name of places?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, game-center

So I am trying to make a game that is similar to flag quiz in the book: IOS 8 for programmers at http://www.deitel.com/Books/iOS/iOS8forProgrammers/tabid/3638/Default.aspx

I tried to remove therir library of flag photos and switch it with places. Is there a simple approach I can take to use this?

Here is a link to the photo: https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/ios-8-for/9780133965315/graphics/158fig01.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have this particular book, but there is likely an array or database with the file names of the images in the Images.xcassets directory.

Once you have added your own new images for places, look for this array and replace the flag photo names with the names of your places.

The same array or database will probably also have the answers too which you can swap out.

Comment: Yea that sounds right. Give me a day to look over it.